# Sent ETC from hardware wallet to ETH address on poloniex

Tags: ethereum-classic

I mistakenly sent ETC from my hardware wallet to an ETH address on poloniex. I sent an email to Poloniex helpdesk and they sent me over here to resolve the issue. I've read online that people have made similar mistakes as me and have been able to recover there coins.

Here is my response from Poloniex.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually appears that you may have emailed the Ethereum Foundation instead of Poloniex; Hudson Jameson is part of the Ethereum Foundation and not Poloniex.

Log into Poloniex's customer support portal [here](https://poloniex.freshdesk.com/support/login) and provide them with [your tx id](https://gastracker.io//tx/0xb0dc1e6fd7f93ae6d91645ae5faf75454a64f3cb148d33cc50a69bdd7797e1d5), as you did above. Let them know what happened.

Poloniex controls the private keys and, therefore, should be able credit your account the ETC to the amount that was sent to your ETH deposit address.

Comment: You are correct. I forgot that I had sent emails to both Poloniex and Ethereum Foundation and I assumed the email was from Poloniex. Poloniex got back to me and they were able to credit me with my etc.